# Hibernate : CascadeType.PERSIST does not work but CascadeType.ALL to save object

Tags: hibernate, cascade

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Section_INST")
public class Section {

@javax.persistence.Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "Section_ID_GENERATOR")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "Section_ID_GENERATOR",sequenceName = "Section_ID_SEQUENCER" , initialValue = 1 , allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "Section_ID")
private int Id;

@Column(name = "Section_Name")
private String name;

@OneToOne(optional = false,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "Exch_ID")
private Exchange exchange;

//---Constructor and Getter Setters-----
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "EXCHANGE_INST")
public class Exchange {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "Exchange_ID_GENERATOR")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "Exchange_ID_GENERATOR",sequenceName = "Exchange_ID_SEQUENCER" , initialValue = 1 , allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "Exchange_ID")
private int Id;

@Column(name = "Exchange_name")
private String name;

@OneToOne(mappedBy ="exchange")
private Section section;

//-----------Getter and Setter...And Constructor
```

}

The following program does not work ->

```
    final SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    final Exchange exchange = new Exchange("MyExchange");
    final Section section = new Section("MySection" , exchange);
    exchange.setSection(section);
    session.save(section);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

If i change cascade options in Section.java to CascadeType.ALL then it works.

```
@OneToOne(optional = false,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)   --- > CascadeType.ALL 
@JoinColumn(name = "Exch_ID")
private Exchange exchange;
```

I think PERSIST should save my object d=, but it throws exception :

org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation: Section.exchange -> Exchange

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For the `save()` operation to be cascaded, you need to enable [`CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html#SAVE_UPDATE), using the proprietary Hibernate [Cascade](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Cascade.html) annotation, since save() is not a standard JPA operation. Or you need to use the `persist()` method, and not the `save()` method.

Comment: I've lost several hours of my life I'll never get back because of this, so thanks!  This is not obvious and poorly documented.  A bit more info: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=951275

Comment: So many hours I have lost... because... of that ORM documentation... =(

Comment: If on updating parent object, i donot want child to be updated. Then how can we achieve this if we are using SAVE_UPDATE?