# Cascade.ALL works, but PERSIST on its own fails: "save the transient instance before flushing"

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Illustration of issue: Team 1..1  <------>  0..* Member

I don't want a pointer from Member to Team, only a Set of Members in Team. The code looks something like this.

```
Team t = new Team("t");
Member m1 = new Member("m1");
t.members.add(m1);
...
session.save(t);
```

If I define the Set as

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<Member> members;
```

...it works as expected, but...

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.DETACH,
    CascadeType.REFRESH,
    CascadeType.REMOVE,
    CascadeType.MERGE })
public Set<Member> members;
```

...it fails with a

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: tmp.Member
```

Of course there are easy workarounds but I'd like to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a bit more I found this answer: [Hibernate : CascadeType.PERSIST does not work but CascadeType.ALL to save object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378605/hibernate-cascadetype-persist-does-not-work-but-cascadetype-all-to-save-object) which fixes the problem