# hibernate annotations confusion

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have two tables say parent and child. Requirement is whenever we add entry to parent, insert should also happen in child. But when we update parent child should not get updated. Which hibernate annotation (CascadeType) should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have `List<Child>` in `Parent` class.

So annotation will be like

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<Child>();
```

According to [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/):

> CascadeType.PERSIST : means that save() or persist() operations cascade to related entities.

Comment: Thanks for replying. CascadeType.PERSIST is not saving the child record. I am doing session.save(parent)

Comment: The complete details can be found in a separate stackoverflow question which I posted sometime back  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41084320/confusion-in-giving-hibernate-association-annotation. Please help i am working on weekend breaking my head on this from past several hours

Comment: @user3681970 after `session.save(parent)` can you see records in parent table?

Comment: Yes. I can see in parent table but not in child table. This might be because of   https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/