# OneToMany child entities not persisted on save()

Tags: java, hibernate

I am running into the following behaviour in hibernate which I can't explain and I was hoping that someone can provide an explanation of what is going on.

I have a bidirectional `@OneToMany` association between `Instructor` and `Course`. Since they have a `CascadeType.PERSIST` I am expecting that when I create a `Course` object and associate it to `Instructor` and vice versa and then call the `.save()` method on the instructor both objects will be persisted in the database, although that results in only the `Instructor` to be persisted without the courses.

If I call the `persist()` method for ex: `session.persist(instructor)` both instructor and the courses are persisted.

Here are my entities and my main method.

Instructor:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "instructor")
public class Instructor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_detail_id")
    private InstructorDetail instructorDetail;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instructor", cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,
    CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();

    public Instructor() {
    }

    public Instructor(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public InstructorDetail getInstructorDetail() {
        return instructorDetail;
    }

    public void setInstructorDetail(InstructorDetail instructorDetail) {
        this.instructorDetail = instructorDetail;
    }

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(List<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Instructor{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", instructorDetail=" + instructorDetail +
            ", courses=" + courses +
            '}';
    }

    public void addCourse(Course course) {
        courses.add(course);
        course.setInstructor(this);
    }
}
```

Course

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "instructor_id")
    private Instructor instructor;

    public Course(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Instructor getInstructor() {
        return instructor;
    }

    public void setInstructor(Instructor instructor) {
        this.instructor = instructor;
    }
}
```

Main

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create session factory
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
            .configure("com/ysoft/config/hibernate.cfg.xml")
            .addAnnotatedClass(Instructor.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(InstructorDetail.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(Course.class)
            .buildSessionFactory();

        //create session
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        try (sessionFactory) {
            session.beginTransaction();

            Instructor instructor = new Instructor("John", "Doe", "John.Doe@email.com");
            InstructorDetail instructorDetail = new InstructorDetail("http://www.something.com", "Coding");

            Course mathCourse = new Course("Math");
            Course englishCourse = new Course("English");
            Course sportsCourse = new Course("Sports");

            instructor.addCourse(mathCourse);
            instructor.addCourse(englishCourse);
            instructor.addCourse(sportsCourse);

            instructor.setInstructorDetail(instructorDetail);

            session.save(instructor);

            session.getTransaction().commit();

            System.out.println("Persisted" + instructor);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I changed the `@OneToMany` cascade array to `CascadeType.ALL` then it worked - but I don't know why, since the relevant types were already there.

The child side shouldn't have cascade specified - to quote the latest Hibernate docs:

> The `@OneToMany` association is by definition a parent association, even
>   if it’s a unidirectional or a bidirectional one. Only the parent side
>   of an association makes sense to cascade its entity state transitions
>   to children.

**Update:**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17378605/hibernate-cascadetype-persist-does-not-work-but-cascadetype-all-to-save-object) it seems calling `save()` rather than using JPA `EntityManager.persist()` it also needs Hibernate-specific cascade type `SAVE_UPDATE`. (Which isn't compatible with JPA `@OneToMany` definition)